# NAS VPN vs dedicated VPN Server for Home Network

Tags: vpn, nas

I've got a NAS at home and want to access the files, pictures etc remotely. The NAS has VPN Server (L2TP/IPSec and OpenVPN) functionality and I was planing on using this and enabling port forwarding on the router.

I wanted to check if there is any value in having a separate device as a VPN server, maybe RaspberryPI? or if I should get a Router with VPN server capability? It's a QNAP NAS if that makes any difference.

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summary:

1. Best option would be a router with VPN capability (but $$)
2. Next get the QNAS to act as VPN (because its free)
3. Getting a PI or similar would be least beneficial. (because its complex and not going to perform much better then option 2, and worse then option 1 if its a decent router)

Long version:

Getting a router with VPN server capability is the best way to go from a technical POV because it simplifies routing, offers the VPN service at the point where its most beneficial - the edge of the network - and allows additional functionality to access other parts of your LAN securely.  This is the way I would do it.   It can also offload the VPN task from the QNAS VPN, but this is not likely to significantly impact performance.

Probably not worth getting a PI (as opposed to having the NAS do the heavy lifting).  Having a VPN device like a PI is going to make the routing significantly more complex, and the only benefit would be to reduce the CPU load.  Assuming you are using the NAS box primarily as a NAS (ie not focused on other bells and whistles functions it may have), it should not be an issue because a NAS is typically IO bound, and VPN's would be utilise processor.

I also note that most modern CPU's (including those in many QNAP devices) have AES instructions - if your NAS does have a processor with support for AES, and OpenVPN uses it - which it probably will - then it would not even use that much processor.

Comment: About AES: It might be noteworthy that OpenVPN by default does not use AES. Instead, it must be configured to do so, using the `cipher` option.

Comment: @DanielB Interesting. My out-the-box OpenVPN (2.3.10 for Ubuntu) prefers AES ciphers first (at least when I run openvpn --show-tls).  The same is true on my OpenVPN 2.3.12 client running on OpenVPN.     Am I missing something ?

Comment: The data channel does not use TLS. By default, it results in this configuration: “Data Channel Encrypt: Cipher 'BF-CBC' initialized with 128 bit key”

Comment: @Danielb - Thank you - I just learn something new.

Comment: thank you all! i will look into the router options, but will stick with the QNAP for now.